# What do I do with sun scorched bell pepper leaves

Tags: leaves

I live in Florida and have recently started attempting to grow bell peppers. My plants are in a planter and are @ 8 inches tall. But now some of the leaves are sun scorched/burnt. Should I remove the scorched leaves?

Answer (score 1):

That's a really good question, and while I don't 100% know the answer, if the scorched portions are completely dead, I don't think it should matter terribly, except to be tidy (which I think plants might like). I mean, if it's dead, it shouldn't be counted toward the leaf matter on the plant (and thus shouldn't impact the growth), is what I'm thinking.

If the scorched parts would invite disease, I'd take them off. I'm not sure if they would. If they wouldn't I'd consider leaving them on, since the plant is only 8" tall.

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons to remove:

- the dead leaves are blocking sunlight, which is scarce outside summer
- the dead leaves are touching the ground or are accumulating moisture, thus becoming possible vectors for maladies
- aesthetic reasons
- improved air circulation (which I have no idea why should be important but see it mentioned a lot)

Reasons to keep:

- when they drop, dead leaves form natural mulch
- less effort, more natural plant
- as a reminder to do something about the heat next summer

Answer (score 0):

Some plants get stressed easily, specially if they're in a pot, which either gets too dry or holds too much water with, no drainage. The result might be some leaves dying in either extreme. Some plants under those conditions get Sun burned in extreme weather so just like you would do perhaps give them partial shade during the most daunting part of the day and see how they cope.